# Changed Context Store but Browser loads the old Store

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have created a Context Store using React Context API. I am also using NextJS.
Now I am in the process of refactoring it and having the schema of it a bit differently since the way I did it first didn't allow for much, which I only realised later.

So now I am going from file to file to correct the selectors.

Inside a file, I did a console.log to view the context and see if I am doing anything wrong because I am getting an error, that something is undefined.

The console.log inside my Terminal shows me the correct context, where the objects exist and should *not* show any undefined.
BUT inside the dev console, it still shows me the *old* context.

## What I have tried

- I have already restarted the server as well as hard-refreshed the page (both F5 and Shift+F5)
- This occurs on Chrome, Chrome Incognito and Firefox.
- I have also deleted the contents of the `.next` folder.

What can I do?

## Some Code

### The Consumer Part:

```js
        <StoneContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => {
            console.group('Kontext');
            console.log(context);
            console.log(context.stoneContext.columns.dropzone.stoneIds);
            console.groupEnd();

            const activeStones = context.stoneContext.columns.dropzone.stoneIds;
            return (
              <ul>
                {activeStones.map((activeStone) => {
                  return <li key={activeStone.id}>{activeStone.content}</li>;
                })}
              </ul>
            );
          }}
        </StoneContext.Consumer>
```

### The Error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropzone' of undefined

```js
  33 |             console.group('Kontext');
  34 |             console.log(context);
> 35 |             console.log(context.stoneContext.columns.dropzone.stoneIds);
     |                                                     ^
  36 |             console.groupEnd();
  37 | 
  38 |             const activeStones = context.stoneContext.columns.dropzone.stoneIds;
```

### The Store:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import initialStones from './initialStones';

export const StoneContext = createContext();
StoneContext.displayName = 'Stone Context';

export default function StoneStore(props) {
  const [stoneContext, setStoneContext] = useState(initialStones);

  return (
    <StoneContext.Provider value={{ stoneContext, setStoneContext }}>
      {props.children}
    </StoneContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

## some images

### Dev Console

[image]

### Terminal

[image]

### Error Message

[image]

---

And again, the code worked *perfectly fine* before I decided to update the Store with different Values.

---

I have *new* info on my problem.
I checked the console again and my console.log is being printed four times.
the first two times are being printed correctly, with the correct data.
the next two are printed with the old data:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed, and it was a really stupid problem. I was refactoring everything until I got to this point, meaning I didn't manage to refactor *everything* yet.

In another file, I was overwriting the Store inside a `useEffect` and this is what was happening.